# Choosing between up and above in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I have always been confused about the use of **above** and **up**. Lets say I in grocery store and I am supposed to describe the position of X in a high rack.

Should I say "It is 3 shelves up and in the back/front (of that shelf)." or "It is 5 shelves above and in the front."?

Can anyone please explain to me which is correct and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could say

> It is 3 rows up and in the back/front.

although there should be some reference as to up from where, unless you are looking at that row.  You could say

> It is 3 rows up **from the middle shelf**, and in the back/front.

In the case of

> It is 5 rows above and in the front.

you have to specify above what. In this case you would not use above by itself. You could say

> It is 5 rows above the vanilla ice cream and in the front.

Also, in a grocery store, it is more likely to say *shelves* rather than *rows*.

Answer (score 1):

The two could imply the same thing, but may not be used the way you have them in your examples. *Up* implies direction as in "up and down". So your first example implies that you go to the back/front of the store, then three rows up(side) and you will find the item you are looking for. The second one seems ungrammatical as is. You need something after *above*. It's five rows above the *red line*... Or something. You can use above all by itself in a different context for example:

> Read the text *above*. *Here the text is already mentioned and the user knows about it*